# Displaying yes or no instead of 1 or 0 in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way I can annotate a field of my view so that it displays yes instead of one and no instead of 0 in my view?  I know there is a display attribute that takes the name and displays something different, but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Just curious, why are you not using a boolean?

Comment: It's the way the dba's designed the system.  So instead of dealing with all kind of conversion issues on my webservices I figured just passed it to the view.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense.  Was just curious since Yes/No corresponds more to True/False.

Answer (score 4):

Create [Display Template](http://digitaltoolfactory.net/blog/2012/04/how-to-use-ui-hints-and-display-templates-in-asp-net-mvc-3/) with name "YesNo"

```
@model int

@(Model == 0 ? "No" : "Yes")
```

And add attribute to field of your model

```
[UIHint("YesNo")]
public int Value { get; set; }
```

When you will display your model then `"YesNo"` display template will be used.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Value) // output "Yes" or "No"
```

Comment: And for editing using RadioButtons?  Same concept excpet something like
@Model int
@Html.RadioButton("Yes", 1)?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. The simplest is to add some "display logic" in your View.

```
@(Model.YesNo == 1 ? "Yes" : "No")
```

I would create an Enum type and use it instead of an int on your model.

```
public enum YesNo
{
  No = 0,
  Yes, 1
}
```

Then your view would simply have

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.YesNo)
```